# How to hide a div if the user cicks anywhere on the page except 2 elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup:

```
<a href="" id="clickMe">Click Me</a>

<div id="foo" style="border:1px solid red; display:hidden"></div>
```

My code to get the "foo" div to show on click.

```
$('#clickMe').click(function(e) {
    $('#foo').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now how can I hide the div again **IF THE USER CLICKS ANYWHERE ON THE PAGE EXCEPT THE DIV ITSELF OR THE CLICK ME LINK?**

Note: I need to be able to do this without changing the markup.

Comment: Evidently that's an important part of his criteria. I'll make sure to address it in my answer.

Comment: @Greg lol, well this is a very serious matter :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#clickMe').click(function(e) {
    $('#foo').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});


$("#clickMe, #foo").mouseup(function(){return false;});

$(document).mouseup(function(e){//removes menu when clicked on any other part of page
    if($("#foo:visible").length > 0  ){
        $('#foo').hide();
    }
});
```

[Example on JSFIDDLE.net](http://jsfiddle.net/lonewolfs/tMT6C/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).click(function() {     
    $("#foo").hide();
}); 

$("#foo, #clickMe").click(function() {     
 return false;
});
```

Comment: More elegant than my solution, but I think you should add `$('#foo').show();` before `return false;`

Comment: @Peter that is already being addressed by OP (as posted in his question)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clickMe, #foo').click(function() {
    $('#foo').show();
    return false;
});

$(":not(#clickMe, #foo)").click(function() {
    $('#foo').hide();
});
```

Check it out on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ehND/).

Comment: Binding the event handler to every single element besides #clickMe and #foo is bad for performance, especially on a page with a large number of elements.  It would be better to bind it to the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can [put a click handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on `document.body` so it gets clicks from every element on the page. You can check the [target property of the event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target) to see what was actually clicked on and if it does not have the ID's of those two elements you can [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) your `<div>`.

```
$(document.body).click(function(event){
   var targetID = $(event.target).attr("id");
   if( targetID !== "clickMe" && targetID !== "foo" ){
      $("#foo").hide();
   }
});
```

[Try it out!](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/TcVYU/)